# Using PBKDF2 key derivation to properly create user-readable salt with rust-crypto

Tags: cryptography, rust

I am currently working on creating a client for [Standard File](https://github.com/standardnotes/doc/blob/master/Client%20Development%20Guide.md), which involves using PBKDF2 for security. I'm using **rust-crypto**, although I have experimented with ring and rust-openssl.

First, you retrieve a salt, cost and version number from the server through the `/auth/param` endpoint. I have these serialized into a struct with Serde.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct PWHash {
    pub pw_salt: String,
    pub pw_cost: u32,
    pub version: String,
}
```

Previous clients I have looked at implemented using Python, where the PBKDF2 functions all seem to accept strings. However, for PBKDF2 with Rust, they all accept `&[u8]` as the parameter.

I use `.as_bytes()` when calling the function, and then `str::from_utf8` to output the derived key. However, when doing so, it fails with `Err(Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 0, error_len: Some(1) })`.

Here is a code snippet:

```
pub fn hashcompute(&self, password: String) {
    let mut dk = [0u8; 768]; // derived key
    let mut mac = Hmac::new(Sha512::new(), password.as_bytes());
    pbkdf2::pbkdf2(&mut mac, self.pw_salt.as_bytes(), self.pw_cost, &mut dk);

    println!("{:?}", str::from_utf8(&dk));
}
```

Even `String::from_utf8_lossy` returns a result of unreadable characters.

How do I properly format a Rust string for proper cryptographic use? Is there another library that is functional? Or is this a lost cause?

Comment: Why would you expect the key to be proper UTF-8?

Comment: @mcarton I'm guessing that's part of the "user-readable" part. Wild guess: other languages automatically hex- or base64-encode the raw data.

Comment: @Shepmaster: your comment shows exactly why automatically encoding the raw data would be a bad idea: there are two (common) ways to represent a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Standard File [documentation](http://standardfile.org/#client-instructions), the key should be hex-encoded (see the comments in the code sample). So something like this should work:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize as serialize;
use serialize::hex::{FromHex, ToHex};

pub fn hashcompute(&self, password: String) {
    let mut dk = [0u8; 768]; // derived key
    let mut mac = Hmac::new(Sha512::new(), password.as_bytes());
    pbkdf2::pbkdf2(&mut mac, self.pw_salt.from_hex().unwrap(), self.pw_cost, &mut dk);

    println!("{}", dk.to_hex());
}
```

Note that I've also used `from_hex` to convert the salt from a string to a `&[u8]` since it looks like the salt should also be hex-encoded.

Comment: `rustc_serialize` is deprecated, usually in favour of `serde`, but for once, I don't think `serde` has this feature. There is a [`hex`](https://docs.rs/hex/0.3.1/hex/) crate which seems to well suited, although I've never used it.

Comment: how to decrypt this